Which metrics should I set alerts on - Azure SQL Server
I've decided to set alerts for the following on my Azure SQL Database:

CPU Usage.
Memory Usage.
Longest query time (from request arrives to results returned so it includes time in the queue).

In the Azure Metrics for CPU time it has the following - which is the measure that lets me know when the DB is getting overloaded:

CPU Percentage
SQL Instance CPU percent
SQL Server Process core percent

And for memory it has:

SQL Instance memory percent
SQL Server Process memory percent

And I can't find anything that I think is tracking how long a request is taking although I'm guessing it must have that and I don't know what it is called.

You should use the sys.dm_db_resource_stats and track:

AVG/MAX avg_cpu_percent
AVG/MAX avg_data_io_percent
AVG/MAX avg_log_write_percent
AVG/MAX avg_memory_usage_percent
MAX max_worker_percent

This way:
SELECT
    database_name = DB_NAME(),
    AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Average CPU use in percent',
    MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS 'Maximum CPU use in percent',
    AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Average data IO in percent',
    MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS 'Maximum data IO in percent',
    AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Average log write use in percent',
    MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS 'Maximum log write use in percent',
    AVG(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Average memory use in percent',
    MAX(avg_memory_usage_percent) AS 'Maximum memory use in percent',
    MAX(max_worker_percent) AS 'Maximum worker use in percent'
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats

Or the sys.resource_stats and track the same but for the last 7 days pu to 14 days but no further than that (there are no logs):
SELECT rs.database_name
,    rs.sku
,    storage_mb                           = MAX(rs.storage_in_megabytes)
,    'Average CPU Utilization In %'       = AVG(rs.avg_cpu_percent)
,    'Maximum CPU Utilization In %'       = MAX(rs.avg_cpu_percent)
,    'Average Data IO In %'               = AVG(rs.avg_data_io_percent)
,    'Maximum Data IO In %'               = MAX(rs.avg_data_io_percent)
,    'Average Log Write Utilization In %' = AVG(rs.avg_log_write_percent)
,    'Maximum Log Write Utilization In %' = MAX(rs.avg_log_write_percent)
,    'Maximum Requests In %'              = MAX(rs.max_worker_percent)
,    'Maximum Sessions In %'              = MAX(rs.max_session_percent)
FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs
WHERE rs.database_name = 'userdb1' 
AND rs.start_time > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY rs.database_name, rs.sku;

But I now have a question for you: what is your goal? Are you going to use the Alert feature in the left bar menu?

Because in that case you are going to be spammed daily and it will lead to nowhere.
Is you goal to reduce costs, have better performance or both of them?

Primary is I want to know when I have a problem. Secondary is to know if the DB is getting overloaded. TIA
